# A red exclamation sign also errors in update

Tags: updates, notification

There is a red exclamation sign in the notification area.
When I run `sudo apt-get update` the state of terminal is below:

```
Ign http: //bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe  Translation-en_US
Fetched 3,826 kB in 54s (70.5 kB/s)
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension<br>
W: GPG error: http: //download.opensuse.org ./ Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1436387333
W: Failed to fetch http: //ppa.launchpad.net/disper-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http: //ppa.launchpad.net/disper-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http: //ppa.launchpad.net/disper-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found   
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The PPA doesn't provides packages for Trusty and newer. Check [this link](http://ppa.launchpad.net/disper-dev/ppa/ubuntu/dists/).

*Therefore*

- remove

  Without a downgrade of the installed packages from this PPA

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/disper-dev-ubuntu-ppa*
  ```

**or**

- purge

  Downgrades all packages from this PPA, if possible

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:disper-dev/ppa
  ```

After that

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: +1 but why not using `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:disper-dev/ppa`? It's in Ubuntu by default

Comment: @kos For the downgrade of the installed packages, I hope so. :\

Comment: Yep, sorry, it was a nonsense, indeed old packages should be removed first